# Kali Linux 2.0: Can't install build-essential(s)

Tags: debian, apt, kali-linux, gcc

I recently installed Kali 2.0 minimal on a Virtual Machine. More specifically, 26 GiB Virtual HD, Macbook Air as the host of the VirtualBox.

Immediately after installing, I went to install GCC, and to do so you need to install build-essential(s). However, when I try to install build-essential(s), I get this error: http://pastebin.com/bK8xN9rD

After a quick google search, the relative consensus is that I need to update the system and update my keyring. However, after following advice as to how to do this from multiple forums, I have had no luck, as updating returns this: http://pastebin.com/wVDy9Xcf

Is there something else I need to be doing, or am I not following the steps properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

> Kali sana (2.0) is Retired as you can see from above kali doc link.

To upgrade to rolling refer to this documentation:
https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-rolling-edition-2016-1/
Where you will find the section "**Transitioning From Kali 2.0 to Kali Rolling**"

> As per their docs: **Please note that the Kali sana repositories will
>   no longer be updated and will be EOL’d on the 15th of April 2016.**

Answer (score 1):

backup repository list

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

Add the Kali rolling repository to the list of repositories using :

```
cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
EOF
```

Then comment the following line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then update the package database and upgrade the system using the following:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade 
reboot
```

install `build-essential`

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
```